# L1-regularized least squares with equality constraints as a QP problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Is it possible to write the following optimization problem as a quadratic programming problem:

$$
\| y - X\beta\|^2_2 + \lambda \|C\beta\|_1
$$
such that $D\beta = d$ and $D$ has full row rank.

I am thinking whether below is a possibility:
$$
\| y - X\beta\|^2_2 + \lambda \|C\beta\|_1 = \| y - X\beta\|^2_2 + \lambda \|z\|_1 \qquad \qquad \text{s.t}\ z = C\beta,\ \text{and}\ D\beta = d
$$

Can we replace $\|z\|_1$ as $t^\top1$ such that $-t < z < t$?

Comment: If your problem was how to write the 1-norm then yes, this is the standard way to convert it into something linear. https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/linear.html#the-ell-1-norm

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Does that mean I can restate the objective function as $\| w\|_2^2 + \lambda t^\top 1$ such that $w = y - X\beta$, $z = C\beta$, $D\beta = d$ and $-t < z < t$. If so, I can rearrange the terms to that it is similar to a quadratic programming problem with both equality and inequality constraints.

Comment: Yes that looks good. It is an SOCP or QP.